# Convert Oracle table data in to daily data (sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in below format (sample data) where start and end timestamp gets change when the status changes. Everytime the status changes start and end time will be recorded.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Server  Start           End Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a   3/5/2021  11:20 3/5/2021 11:23  Target Down
a   3/5/2021  11:23 3/24/2021 13:00 Target Up
a   3/24/202  113:00    3/24/2021 13:23 Target Down
a   3/24/2021 13:23     Null    Target Up
```

the data is spawned for many days or months. Can this be split into daily data as below

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Server  date        downtime in min
----------------------------------------------------------------
a   3/5/2021        3
a   3/6/2021        0
a   3/7/2021        0
a   .       .
a   .       .
a   3/23/2021       0   
a   3/24/2021       23
```

I created a daily table with dates as in calender and tried to get the required results but not successful.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Please help us to help you.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. Create a calendar table (as you were trying to do). Reference your `servers` table (I assume you have one - showing all servers you must report on, one row per server); in my query, since I don't have your tables, I create a view called `servers` by just selecting the distinct servers from the `server_status` table, but in your actual use case you shouldn't need that, you should instead reference your existing `servers` table, or whatever it is called.

Now cross-join the `calendar` and `servers` tables/views. Then left-outer-join the result to the `server_status` table, on server and on a condition on dates - the condition is that the "date" from the calendar overlaps the "target down" time range from the `server_status` table. (Note that we only need to look at the "target down" rows - we don't actually need the other rows.)

Then compute the minutes down "for that server and that date" for each row in the join, and group by server and calendar date and take the sum of minutes. This last step is necessary because a single server may be down more than once "on the same calendar date".

Here is the query:

```
with
  calendar (dt) as (
    select  date '2021-03-01' + level - 1
    from    dual
    connect by level <= 31
  )
, servers (server) as (
    select distinct server from server_status
  )
select s.server, to_char(c.dt, 'fmmm/dd/yyyy') as dt,
       sum(nvl(round(1440 * ( least(c.dt + 1, nvl(ss.end_dt, c.dt + 1)) 
                                     - greatest(c.dt, ss.start_dt)
                            )
                    )
              , 0 
              )
          ) as mins
from   servers s cross join calendar c
                 left  join server_status ss
                       on  s.server  = ss.server
                       and ss.status = 'Target Down'
                       and (ss.end_dt is null or ss.end_dt > c.dt)
                       and ss.start_dt < c.dt + 1
group   by s.server, c.dt
order   by s.server, c.dt
;
```

I tested it on the following data. Note that I included two servers in my sample; in addition to all the data you provided for `a`, I added `b` with a few more interesting situations: down time spanning over midnight, down time ending at midnight, down time more than once on the same calendar date, down time spanning over more than a full calendar date, etc.

I am not showing the output (62 rows - too much) but anyone who wants to test this solution **or their own solution** can use the code below to recreate the sample:

```
drop table server_status purge;

create table server_status (
    server    varchar2(10),
    start_dt  date,
    end_dt    date,
    status    varchar2(20)
);

alter session set nls_date_format = 'fmmm/dd/yyyy fmhh24:mi';

insert into server_status (server, start_dt, end_dt, status)
  select 'a', to_date('3/5/2021 11:20') , to_date('3/5/2021 11:23') , 'Target Down' from dual union all
  select 'a', to_date('3/5/2021 11:23') , to_date('3/24/2021 13:00'), 'Target Up'   from dual union all
  select 'a', to_date('3/24/2021 13:00'), to_date('3/24/2021 13:23'), 'Target Down' from dual union all
  select 'a', to_date('3/24/2021 13:23'), null                      , 'Target Up'   from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/20/2021 05:00'), to_date('3/21/2021 00:00'), 'Target Down' from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/21/2021 00:00'), to_date('3/25/2021 23:54'), 'Target Up'   from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/25/2021 23:54'), to_date('3/26/2021 00:02'), 'Target Down' from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/26/2021 00:02'), to_date('3/26/2021 22:04'), 'Target Up'   from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/26/2021 22:04'), to_date('3/28/2021 00:10'), 'Target Down' from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/28/2021 00:10'), to_date('3/30/2021 08:44'), 'Target Up'   from dual union all
  select 'b', to_date('3/30/2021 08:44'), null                      , 'Target Down' from dual
;

commit;
```

Comment: Query Covers all required scenarios to me and it worked like a charm :)